# How to configure Texlipse so that it yields .pdf by defaut, instead of .dvi?

Tags: eclipse, pdf, configuration

The question is in the title. It should be silly. But... I really don't see how!
The following are my building paths. Can anyone help ? The goal is to use pdf4eclipse and have a side-by-side view inside eclipse.

[image: my building paths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the output format in properties of your Latex project:

[image]

This has to be done on every Latex project. AFAIR there is no general settings that would allow to change this for all current and new projects.